# Different Domains With NGINX

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, dns, webserver

I am currently hosting a flask/python website on my Amazon Ubuntu EC2 Instance with multiple subdomains including (https://minecraft.server-lists.com). However, I am trying to host a WordPress site on the same machine with a different URL (https://snattire.com).

Currently for some reason when I add my new domain to the sites-enabled folder only this Minecraft site works and the other just gives "This site can’t be reached". However, when I remove the Minecraft Nginx configuration the Snattire domain works perfectly fine. Both just don't want to work at the same time?

**minecraft.server-lists.com NGINX Configuration**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name minecraft.server-lists.com;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    access_log /var/log/serverlist/mcprogram_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/serverlist/mcprogram_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_intercept_errors off;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/PCServerlist/mcprogram.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static {
        # handle static files directly, without forwarding to the application
        root /home/ubuntu/PCServerlist/application/static;
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```

**Snattire NGINX Configuration**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name snattire.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.snattire.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.snattire.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    access_log /var/log/nginx/snattire.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/snattire.com.error.log;

    root /var/www/html/snattire.com;
    index index.php;


        location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        }

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.snattire.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/snattire.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/snattire.com.error.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.snattire.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.snattire.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    return 301 https://snattire.com$request_uri;

}
server {
    if ($host = snattire.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.snattire.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name snattire.com www.snattire.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/snattire.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/snattire.com.error.log;

    return 301 https://snattire.com$request_uri;




}
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 server-lists.com
127.0.0.1 minecraft.server-lists.com
127.0.0.1 admin.server-lists.com
127.0.0.1 snattire.com
127.0.0.1 www.snattire.com
127.0.0.1 db.server-lists.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

The NGINX access & error logs contain no information when trying to access the domain, i.e there is nothing written at all, almost like the mc domain is overriding it? (FYI, I am currently testing with just the Minecraft subdomain and snattire, all the others in /etc/hosts are disabled when I am debugging)

I appreciate the help,

Jack

Comment: It has nothing to do with your question, but you'd better use `root /home/ubuntu/PCServerlist/application;` instead of `alias /home/ubuntu/PCServerlist/application/static;`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure really good with NGINX, but i think you can

1. Get 2 IP Addresses (pay for both)
2. Use multiple port method

   - open your apps on different ports
   - add "proxy_pass http://localhost: to EACH server block

helpful tutorial: http://randomdotnext.com/host-multiple-sites-on-single-ec2-instance-nginx-node/

In apache, you would use virtual hosts, but idk how to do that with NGINX

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, ideally I would like to keep using NGINX if possible :)

Comment: Unfortunatley trying your method still didnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was a bug in Ubuntu 18 & updating to Ubuntu 20 fixed it.